# JavaScript call function inside of itself

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have something like this:

```
var MyObject = function () { };

MyObject.prototype = {
    methodA: function() {
           methodB();
    }

    methodB: function() {
           // do something
    }
}
```

How do I get this working?  i keep getting "Object has no method 'methodB'".

Comment: You need a comma after the close brace of `methodA:{}` as well as a `this.methodB();` instead of **just** `methodB();`

Comment: You should get a reference error actually.

Comment: I do have the comma after `methodA:{}`. `this.methodB();` gives me an error in Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'methodB'`

Comment: nevermind, i was calling it inside a $.post return method.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `this` within `methodA`. For example:

```
var MyObject = function () { };

MyObject.prototype = {
    methodA: function() {
           this.methodB();
    },

    methodB: function() {
           alert('foo');
    }
};

var o = new MyObject();
o.methodA(); // foo
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6amJ5/)

Comment: Doesn't work.  In Chrome, i get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'methodB'`

Answer (score 2):

```
this.methodB();
```

this call will work as soon as you instantiate a new object using

```
var newObject = new MyObject();
```